# Put many columns in group by clause in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by

In Oracle 11g database, Suppose we have table, `CUSTOMER` and `PAYMENT` as follows

### Customer

```
CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME | CUSTOMER_AGE | CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------------
001                     John             30              1 Jan 2017
002                     Jack             10              2 Jan 2017
003                      Jim             50              3 Jan 2017
```

### Payment

```
CUSTOMER_ID | PAYMENT_ID | PAYMENT_AMOUNT | 
-------------------------------------------
001                   900            100.00
001                   901            200.00
001                   902            300.00
003                   903            999.00
```

We want to write an SQL to get all columns from table `CUSTOMER` together with the sum of all payment of each customer. There are many possible ways to do this but **I would like to ask which one of the following is better.**

#### Solution 1

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID
, MAX(C.CUSTOMER_NAME) CUSTOMER_NAME
, MAX(C.CUSTOMER_AGE) CUSTOMER_AGE
, MAX(C.CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE) CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE
, SUM(P.PAYMENT_AMOUNT) TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN PAYMENT P ON (P.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID)
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

#### Solution 2

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID
, C.CUSTOMER_NAME
, C.CUSTOMER_AGE
, C.CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE
, SUM(P.PAYMENT_AMOUNT) PAYMENT_AMOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN PAYMENT P ON (P.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID)
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.CUSTOMER_NAME, C.CUSTOMER_AGE, C.CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE
```

Please notice in **Solution 1** that I use `MAX` not because I actually want the max results, but I because I want "ONE" row from the columns which I know are equal for all rows with the same `CUSTOMER_ID`

While in **solution 2**, I avoid putting the misleading `MAX` in `SELECT` part by putting the columns in `GROUP BY` part instead.

With my current knowledge, I prefer **Solution 1** because it is more important to comprehend the logic in `GROUP BY` part than in the `SELECT` part. I would put only a set of unique keys to express the intention of the query, so the application can infer the expected number of rows. But I don't know about the performance.

I ask this question because I am reviewing a code change of a big SQL that put 50 columns in the `GROUP BY` clause because the editor want avoid the `MAX` function in `SELECT` part. I know we can refactor the query in someway to avoid putting the irrelevant columns in both `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` part, but please discard that option because it will affect the application logic and require more time to do the test.

---

## Update

I have just done the test on my big query in both versions as everyone suggested. The query is complex, it has 69 lines involving more than 20 tables and the execution plan is more than 190 lines, so I think this is not the place to show it.

My production data is quite small now, it has about 4000 customers and the query was run against the whole database. Only table `CUSTOMER` and a few reference table has `TABLE ACCESS FULL` in the execution plan, the others tables have access by indexes. The execution plans for both versions have a little bit difference in join algorithm (`HASH GROUP BY` vs `SORT AGGREGATE`) on some part.

Both versions use about 13 minutes, no significant difference.

I also have done the test on the simplified versions similar to the SQL in the question. Both version has exactly the same execution plan and elapse time.

With the current information, I think the most reasonable answer is that it is unpredictable unless test to decide the quality of both versions as the optimizer will do the job. I will very appreciate if anyone could give any information to convince or reject this idea.

Comment: Please qualify what you  mean by "better" ?

Comment: This question alludes to the redundancy of SQL syntax.  Every non-aggregate column in the `select` clause **must** appear in the `group by` clause for the SQL to be valid, and every column in the `group by` clause **ought** to be a non-aggregate column in the `select` clause otherwise the results are potentially ambiguous.  So in my view there should be no need for a `group by` clause at all!

Comment: @Caius Jard, I would like to leave that open for if there is any aspect have never thought of, but what I am concern the most is about the performance.

Comment: That should be pretty easy for you to benchmark for your exact situation; far easier and more accurate than anything we can tell you

Comment: @TonyAndrews yes, but we wouldn't want the database to infer a group by to apply in some situations, for example it's legitimate to say `GROUP BY age` but have a select list of `CASE WHEN age < 20 THEN 'young' ELSE 'old'` - we might not want an auto groupby of `GROUP BY CASE WHEN...`

Comment: @CaiusJard Let the optimizer sort that one out :-)

Comment: @TonyAndrews it can't, because the need for doing something so weird would purely be in the mind of the developer. If age had 4 distinct values of 5, 15, 25 and 35 then `SELECT CASE WHEN age < 20 THEN... GROUP BY age` produces 4 rows, but `SELECT CASE WHEN age ... GROUP BY CASE WHEN age ...` produces 2. Only the developer of the application can know when he wants each form

Comment: @CaiusJard yes but that is exactly the kind of SQL that (in my world) would not be allowed because it produces nonsensical results! e.g. `select case when age<20 then 'young' else 'old' end, count(*) from people group by age` might return {{'young', 3},{'young',2}},... it doesn't really mean anything!

Comment: @TonyAndrews but we might not necessarily be discussing your world; I'm simply proposing that there are situations where it would not be wise to leave the query engine to decide what GROUP BY to apply. I understand the merit of your point, but you're proposing making query engines in general less flexible and powerful by removing something that it's perfectly reasonable to leave to the developer. Perhaps if your suggestion was that in the absence of a GROUP BY, the query engine was allowed to assume one, but if one were supplied it would be used, then I'd agree.

Comment: @CaiusJard This is all by-the-bye as SQL is what it is.  However in my view it would have been nicer if `group by` had never existed, just to cater for the tiny percentage of cases where developers want to produce a dubious result.  They could do that (if they insist) by other means e.g. `select a, b, sum_d from (select a, b, c, sum(d) sum_d from t group by a, b, c);`.

Comment: I meant to write of course: `select a, b, sum_d from (select a, b, c, sum(d) sum_d from t);` (no group by clause!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151967/discussion-between-caius-jard-and-tony-andrews).

Comment: To add another option, there's also a correlated sub-query: `select customer_id, customer_name, customer_age, customer_creation_date, (select sum(payment_amount) from payment where customer_id = c.customer_id) as payment_amount from customer c`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID
, C.CUSTOMER_NAME
, C.CUSTOMER_AGE
, C.CUSTOMER_CREATION_DATE
, P.PAYMENT_AMOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
JOIN (
 SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(PAYMENT_AMOUNT) PAYMENT_AMOUNT
 FROM PAYMENT 
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
) P ON (P.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

To  decide which one of three is better just test them and see the execution plans.

Comment: Thanks, but please assume that we can't do this. I would like to know the different between putting the columns in `group by` vs putting the `MAX` in `select` part

Comment: Do please specify INNER, LEFT, RIGHT or FULL OUTER when writing the JOIN keyword

Comment: The optimizer generally is wise enough to make good  plans for the both your solutions. One may expect excessive sort in the Solution 2 but it totally depends on current optimizer version and may change unpredictably.

Comment: @CaiusJard But INNER is the default and is the commonest join, so can be omitted for sake of brevity without losing clarity.

Comment: @CaiusJard Why? `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN` in any DBMS  present.

Comment: Lots of things could be omitted for brevity, but I'm not certain it makes the statement necessarily more clear

Comment: I think you are in the minority on that, @CaiusJard!

Comment: Indeed. I also pronounce sandwich as sandwitch, not samwidge :)

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Do the sum on payment, then join the results.

```
select C.*, p.total_payment -- c.* gets all columns from table alias c without typing them all out
from Customer C
left join -- I've used left in case you want to include customers with no orders
(
select customer_id, sum(payment_amount) as total_payment
from Payment
group by customer_id
) p
on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

Comment: Why **left** join?

Comment: Thanks, but please assume that we can't do this. I would like to know the different between putting the columns in `group by` vs putting the `MAX` in `select` part

Comment: @asinkxcoswt As serg suggests, run each and view the execution plans

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** is costly.

Even though optimizer could avoid the unecessary sorting,
at some point you will be forced to add indexes/constraints
over irrelevant columns to improve performance.
Not a good practice in the long term.

**Solution 2** is the Oracle way.

Oracle documentation states that:

> GROUP BY clause must contain only aggregates or grouping columns

Oracle engineers had valid reasons to do that, 
however this does not apply to other RDBMS where you
can simply put `GROUP BY c.customerID` and all will be fine.

For the sake of code readability a `--comment` would be cheaper.

In general, not embracing any platform principles would have a cost: 
more code, weird code, memory, disk space, performance, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution 1 the query will repeat the MAX function for each column. I don't know exactly how the MAX function works but I assume that it sorts all elements on the column than pick the first (best case scenario). It is kind of a time bomb, when your table gets bigger this query will get worst very fast. So if you consern about performance you should pick the solution 2. It looks messier but will be better for the application.